# Custom keybindings in vscode devcontainer definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, codespaces

I’m trying to add a couple of key-bindings to my codespace image. But I can’t find where to store the `keybindings.json`, when I open the file in an active codespace it’s located in `/User/keybindings.json`, but I can’t find it in bash or when I try to Open Folder that folder. It seems to be a virtual file.

Is there a way to add these to the `devcontainer.json`? Or a magic place I can send them to from my Docker File?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a number of closed issues, keybindings are considered more a personal preference and are synced from the users' preferences as well as platform dependent.

To supply or override keybindings a custom extension must be created, published to the marketplace and installed through the `devcontainer.json`.